# Python setup.py call makefile don't include binaries

Tags: python, c, setup.py

Some context: I have some C code that when compiled I can call in the terminal like this: `./my_excec -params` It generates some files that I am using in python to generate charts, and other stuff.

I want to pack everything in a python library both the C code and the python code. The C code is not a python extension (prolly going to be in a future but right now is not).

I have a make file to compile the C code and I know I can call it from the setup.py like this:
`subprocess.call(['make', '-C', 'word2vec-src'])`

What I want to be able to do is: `pip install my_module` That should call the makefile, compile the C so the user can call the binaries: `my_excec -params` and also be able to import the python code around it.

The problem I am having is when packaging the python package. I am using the `data_files` option in `setup()` like this:`data_files=[('bin', ['bin/binary_file'])],` This moves the files from bin to the installation folder (in a virtual env) and I can call them. But when packaging is also putting the compiled files in the tarball and when I call pip install my_module` is putting the compiled files from my computer.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was able to find a really easy solution.

As I said my main problem was that I was packaging the compiled files. To exclude those files form the tarball/zip just had to put this on MANIFEST.in: `prune bin`.

Then just need to call the makefile from setup.py:

```
directory = 'bin'
if not os.path.exists(directory):
    os.makedirs(directory)

subprocess.call(['make', '-C', 'src'])
```

With that when someone does `pip install whatever` is going to call the make file and put the binaries on `bin` (have to specify this on the make file).

Then just need to say the setup to copy those files:

```
setup(
...
data_files=[('bin', ['bin/binaries'])],
)
```

Done! Hopefuly someone find this usefull :)

Comment: This is really helpful.  Do you have a link to your full source code somewhere?  I'm interested in how you structured your Makefile.