# Best way to package a Python library that includes a C shared library?

Tags: python, c, distutils

I have written a library whose main functionality is implemented in C (speed is critical), with a thin Python layer around it to deal with the `ctypes` nastiness.

I'm coming to package it and I'm wondering how I might best go about this. The code it must interface with is a shared library. I have a Makefile which builds the C code and creates the `.so` file, but I don't know how I compile this via distutils. Should I just call out to `make` with `subprocess` by overriding the `install` command (if so, is `install` the place for this, or is `build` more appropriate?)

**Update**: I want to note that this is *not* a Python extension. That is, the C library contains no code to itself interact with the Python runtime. Python is making foreign function calls to a straight C shared library.

Comment: Have you got any solution for your problem? I'm stuck with the same question and desperate for an answer ;)

Comment: This is a very long time ago but it looks like I solved this by shelling out to `make`. This is the setup.py from that library: https://gist.github.com/obeattie/3d491ec4c29b1d4b46387b285c91ca89

Comment: I've tried doing what you have in this gist, but... how did you get the `.so` you lined with to get installed in any location Python / ld will look for it?

Answer (score 1):

I'd consider building the python module as a subproject of a normal shared library build.  So, use automake, autoconf or something like that to build the shared library, have a python_bindings directory with a setup.py and your python module.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar need and found this answer helpful: [Python setup.py call makefile don't include binaries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18436061/python-setup-py-call-makefile-dont-include-binaries).

I have an ANSI C library in the `src` directory of my distribution. In the `src` directory is a Makefile that builds a file called `liblsd.so` in my package directory (`lsd`).  I call this in setup.py and then tell setup to include the library file using the `package_data` argument.

```
import os.path
import subprocess

from setuptools import setup

with open(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'README.rst')) as f:
    readme = f.read()

subprocess.call(['make', '-C', 'src'])

setup(name='LSD',
  version='0.0.1',
  description='Python bindings for the LSD line segment detector.',
  long_description=readme,
  author='Geoff Hing',
  author_email='geoffhing@gmail.com',
  url='https://github.com/ghing/python-lsd',
  packages=['lsd'],
  package_data={'lsd': ['liblsd.so']},
  include_package_data=True,
  classifiers=[
      'Development Status :: 1 - Planning',
      'Intended Audience :: Developers',
      'License :: OSI Approved :: MIT License',
      'Operating System :: OS Independent',
      'Programming Language :: Python',
      'Programming Language :: C',
      ],
 )
```

Comment: You should at least sub class `distutils.command.build` and override the `run` method, otherwise the make call will happen for every type of call to setup.py where you may not want to recompile the library (e.g. 'check' or 'upload')

Answer (score 0):

Given that you followed the instructions on how to [create Python extensions in C](https://docs.python.org/2/extending/extending.html), you should just enlist the extension modules like in [this documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/distutils/setupscript.html#describing-extension-modules).
So the `setup.py` script of your library should look like this:

```
from distutils.core import setup, Extension
setup(
   name='your_python_library',
   version='1.0',
   ext_modules=[Extension('your_c_extension', ['your_c_extension.c'])],
)
```

and `distutils` knows how to compile your extension to C shared library and moreover where to put it.

*Of course I have no further information about your library, so you probably want to add more arguments to `setup(...)` call.*

Comment: @ElmoVanKielvo, do you know how to do it in distutils2 ?

Comment: Seems like... http://pythonhosted.org/Distutils2/distutils/setupscript.html#describing-extension-modules ...exactly the same :)

Comment: It is not a Python extension. This is a pure C library (which contains no code itself to interact with the Python runtime), but Python makes calls to it via [`ctypes`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html).

It's potentially possible to wrap the C shared library in a Python extension module, but I'd prefer to keep the current `ctypes` approach.