# Include a non-python entrypoint in PATH with setuptools

Tags: python, setuptools

I have a Python package that I would like to distribute. As part of that package I would like to provide a script written in C. Is there a way to include that as a binary executable along with the Python package?

I tried following the example here: [Python setup.py call makefile don't include binaries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18436061/python-setup-py-call-makefile-dont-include-binaries)

But when I do:

```
python setup.py develop
binary_file
```

`binary_file` doesn't execute. I can confirm that it's being placed in `bin/binary_file` within the site-packages package directory.

Is there a way to get setuptools to add that directory to the current PATH or to link the binary to some folder that is already in PATH so that `binary_file` can be called as a script (similar to how scripts are specified using `scripts: ...` in `setup.py`)?

Comment: `Is there a way to get setuptools to add that directory to the current PATH` — if that's what you're having trouble with, I'd suggest editing the title (seeing that the binary is apparently included correctly).